# Disable button after first click

Tags: java, android

I'm making a game, which include two activities.
I have one

`static  class ModelGetter: public static int getPoint{int static point++;}`.

When click a button in the first activity, the counter is incremented
How can I avoid that in the same activity if I press twice the same button the counter don't incremente a counter two time, but just one?

Comment: That doesn't look like Java

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple: inside the `onClick`, you need to disable the button:

```
yourButton.setEnabled(false);
```

So, when you retry to click it, nothing will happen, since the button is now disabled.

The comple code will be:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {           
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                v.setEnabled(false);
                // increment what you want, or other stuff..
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add onclick handler like -

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").onclick = function() {

    this.disabled = true; // it will disable your button

    //do whatever your logic here or increment your value
}
```

or you can call function on onclick of button like -

```
function clickButton(){

getElementById("buttonId").disabled=true;

//do whatever your logic here or increment your value

}
```

Comment: That's Javascript Moni. Java and Javascript are very different.